# I am trying to find a solution to build a CSS string within my MVC ASP.NET application, Thoughts please?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to find a solution to build a CSS string within my ASP.NET MVC Web Application. I would expect this to be at the selector level. So for example I may have a class "TableFormat" which might have the following CSS string.

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
text-align: left;
background-color: green;
color: White;
```

Instead of having my users needing to know CSS, it would be far better to have a widget that allows them to select a font, color etc and then behind the scenes the widget would construct the above string. I then store this away into the DB for future use in a Razor View. I suspect it is the sort of thing that might exist as a JS widget. However I have not found anything apart from the dedicated CSS builders within bigger packages such as DW.

**So my question is:**

Do you know of a Javascript Control that does this, or another control perhaps within the ASP.NET MVC world that provides the above features. This would map to a textarea field. Otherwise I may need to write my own control.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited my question which hopefully adds clarity.

Comment: Are you building a social network? Why do users need to change their website appearance? Can't you use themes where you create some styles and let users choose from them? What have you found so far? What do you want from us, library our implementation advice?

Comment: No I am not building a social network :) I am building a report generator, and converting XHTML to Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build a backend part where the users would select the properties they want and store it in the database.

Than you can create a new `Controller` that would handle those custom values, something like this

```
public class CssController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Custom()
    {
        ViewData["fontFamily"] = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"; //get from database
        ViewData["fontSize"] = "12px";                           //get from database
        ViewData["selector"] = ".TableFormat";                   //get from database

        return View();
    }
}
```

`Custom.cshtml` View would look something like this

```
@{
     Layout = null;
     Response.ContentType = "text/css";
 }

@ViewData["selector"]
{
     font-family: @ViewData["fontFamily"];
     font-size: @ViewData["fontSize"];
}
```

If you navigate to /css/custom you would see something like this

```
.TableFormat
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Now in the page that you want dynamically generated css you can include the view as a regular css file, for example:

```
 <link href="/Css/Custom" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Huge thanks DZL. Yes your approach is the approach I am currently taking and iterating through the CSS records using LINQ within my Razor View. It works, but with many CSS properties in a "Theme", it can get clunky. That is why I started looking at a solution where I could edit and store the whole CSS string, and delegate the CSS construction and deconstruction to a clever UI widget that would sit ontop of a text area field. However I am getting the feeling that this widget does not exist. Huge thanks again.