# How to dynamically generate CSS file from database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i was going through a post in stackoverflow and the link is [Dynamically generate CSS file from database in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286010/dynamically-generate-css-file-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc/3286360#3286360)

here i am giving the full code and i like to know few thinks from the code.
I think the simplest way would be to add something like the following action method to a controller:

```
public class CssController : Controller
{
    public ContentResult GetTheme()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> css = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>();

        /* Populate css object from the database */

        foreach (var selector in css)
        {
            builder.Append(selector.Key);
            builder.Append(" { ");
            foreach (var entry in selector.Value)
            {
                builder.Append(string.Format("{0}: {1}; ", entry.Key, entry.Value));
            }
            builder.AppendLine("}");
        }

        return Content(builder.ToString(), "text/css");
    }
}
```

Now in your page you can reference it like so:

```
<link href="<%: Url.RouteUrl(new { controller=  "CssController", action = "GetCss" }) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

my question is what file name will show in href ?
the controller CssController & action method GetCss is writing string to out going stream so no file name should show in href....how this code will work?? please guide me to understand this catch......thanks

Comment: href will be "/Css/GetCss"

Comment: we all know that <link href='test.css'> it always point to css file but when we write css to out going string which will be render or included in page then why this approach is required. the above code is not generating any css file on the fly? help me to drive out the confusion. thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are confused about. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820403/i-am-trying-to-find-a-solution-to-build-a-css-string-within-my-mvc-asp-net-appli/17821499#17821499) as well, it might help.

Comment: If there is multiple value then it will generate error

Comment: @DZL thanks the link help me to understand.